# Integral of Dot product of a vector with a constant vector

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

What does this integral equal to?
$$
\int( c^\top x  + q)\,\, dx = ?
$$
In the one dimensional case we know that the integral of a linear function is a quadratic function. Can I say the same and obtain a quadratic form?
All I could think of was this
$$
c^\top x  + q= \text{diag}(c) x  + q= \frac{1}{2} 2\text{diag}(c) x  + q= \nabla_x \left[\frac{1}{2}x^\top \text{diag}(c) x + q^\top x\right]
$$
So that
$$
\int( c^\top x  + q)\,\, dx  = \frac{1}{2}x^\top \text{diag}(c) x + q^\top x + const
$$
Is this true?

Comment: The final identity is certainly true. I don't think there is a nicer formulation of that quantity in terms of mutiplication of matrices, just like sometimes the differentials of matrix maps aren't nicely written in terms of matrix operations.

Comment: what's the definition of $\int ... dx$ that you are using? And what is the meaning of $c^Tx+q$ if $q$ is a vector?

Comment: @CalvinKhor  Good point! Integral I guess integral with respect to the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure

Comment: And for $q$, I made a mistake. I'm not sure what is the structure of a linear function in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @CalvinKhor Would it just be a dot product?

Comment: @CalvinKhor what is the result of $\int q dx$? Is it just $qx$?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking you have a 'type error' because $c^Tx$ and $q$ can't be simply added. So here's a guess at a proper interpretation of the question.

It seems you want something like a fundamental theorem of calculus to hold in higher dimensions. In contrast to your guess in comments to use the Lebesgue integral, I think you want a line integral instead. This gets you the [fundamental theorem of line integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem):
$$ \int_{\gamma[a\to b]} \nabla F(r)\cdot dr=F(b)-F(a)$$
where $F$ is smooth and scalar valued, and $\gamma[a\to b]$ is any path starting from $a$ and ending at $b$. (I suppose you could define an 'indefinite line integral', but I will refrain from doing so.)

For this to work out, you need to identify appropriate gradients to integrate. Note that $$ \nabla(x^TMx)=Mx, \quad \nabla (q^Tx) = q$$
So one gets
$$\int_{\gamma[a\to b]} (Mr+q) \cdot dr = b^TMb +q^Tb - (a^TMa+q^Ta)$$
Note however that we are not integrating a scalar function like $c^Tx$.

If you must integrate $c^Tx$, its hard to guess what would be a good notion of 'indefinite lebesgue integral'. Note that e.g. $\int_{[0,x]^n} c dx = cx^n$; not a linear function.